# Does not match $ as a string in regular expression

Tags: mongodb, go

I am working on a Golang project with Mongodb database. I want to search the string from the db with case insensitive so I have used the regular expression in query like below:

```
var result interface{} 
col := ses.DB("testdb").C("coupons")
err = col.Find(bson.M{"code": bson.RegEx{"^" + code + "$", "i"}}}).One(&result)
```

where code is "OFF$50" but above query does not return result. When I remove the regular expression then it works but in that case it will not work if I pass like "Off$50". I need case insensitive results from db. Can anybody helps me with this query.

Comment: I have no experience with monodb. somewhere I saw  "According to the docs, a `$`sign is reserved for operator in monodb", may be this having any impact in your case ?

Comment: @Arun Yes $ sign use to check in end of the string, but may be there other case to handle this.

Comment: You have to escape `$` by double backslash in `code`

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#regex) uses perl compatible regular expressions([PCRE](https://www.pcre.org)).

A dollar sign `$` in such a regular expression is used to match the end of a line, similar to how a caret `^` matches the beginning of a line.

To match a literal `$` either escape it with backslash `\`, or enclose it in a character class like `[\]`.

Note that because you are passing strings to a function that will build the regular expression, you will likely need to also escape the backslash in the string in order for it to appear in the finished regex, i.e. use 2 backslashes where ever you need one.